# Can I use a part of figure in my published paper to supplementary information of new paper?

Tags: citations, self-plagiarism, supporting-information

I'm researched some material and I want to write two paper to other journals. Can I use a part of figure of first paper to supplementary information of second paper? For example, electrical properties of three samples in a figure of first paper, can I use figure of one sample to supplementary information of second paper? Is it OK to reuse figure with different scale range to supplementary information or main article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think of it as reusing an old figure you avoid self plagiarism simply by citing the original. Perhaps the citation includes "Adapted from...".

But, in changing the scale you might also think of it as a new figure, even if it has the same "shape". Does it convey new information or just restate the old information. You might want to cite the old anyway, just to make things easier for readers needing to go to the old paper.

But, you have an additional issue. If you gave up copyright to the publisher of the old article, you probably need to obtain permission to use the figure in any case (unless it is truly "new"). I doubt that any reputable publisher would deny you permission, but you need to ask to reuse even your own work if you don't hold copyright to it (US perspective - laws vary).